# php : xml parse and return xml

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml

XML parsing isn't working

```
<?php 
$input = "file1.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($input);
$data-content = $xml->data->getAssetResponse->content;
$new-data = str_replace("NEW", "OLD", (string)$data-content);
$xml_object->data->getAssetResponse->content = $new-data;
print $xml_object->asXML(); 
?>
```

May I know why this isn't working?

Comment: Not without more context.  What does the data look like?

Comment: Take a look at this [php variables basics](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)

Comment: Here is my XML<response> <statusCode>200</statusCode> <statusText>OK</statusText> <data> <getAssetResponse> <assetId>89898</assetId> <content> some text with HTML content </content> </getAssetResponse> </data></response> XML

Answer (score 0):

Hyphens are not valid in PHP variable names. I suggest replacing them with underscores instead, as in `$new_data` and `$data_content`.  Finally, you initialize `$xml`, but later are attempting to use the unknown variable `$xml_object`. Change those to `$xml`.

```
$input = "file1.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($input);
$data_content = $xml->data->getAssetResponse->content;
$new_data = str_replace("text", "REPLACED STUFF", (string)$data_content);
$xml->data->getAssetResponse->content = $new_data;
print $xml->asXML(); 

// Outputs:
<response>
  <statusCode>200</statusCode> 
  <statusText>OK</statusText> 
  <data>
    <getAssetResponse> 
      <assetId>89898</assetId> 
      <content> some text with HTML content some REPLACED STUFF with HTML content </content>
    </getAssetResponse> 
  </data>
</response>
```

[From the PHP documentation:](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)

> Variable names follow the same rules as other labels in PHP. A valid variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores. As a regular expression, it would be expressed thus: '[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*'